# Reading multiple lines from an external file - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to sum certain lines from an external file to calculate the total number for those certain lines. Such as there are 31 days in January and I need to add lines 1-31 to calculate a number of defects for that month. I tried using readline and readlines but all I got was the error code: "TypeError: must be str, not int".

Here is my code (formatting is a little off down below):

```
def main():
    print('Hello, this program will calculate the number of defects')
    print('per month and defects per year and average defects per 
    month.')
    counter = 0
    keepGoing = 'x'

jan = feb = mar = apr = may = jun = jul = aug = sep = oct = nov = dec = 0
choice = userSelection()
infile = open('data.txt', 'r')
while keepGoing == 'x':
    if choice == 1:
        keepGoing = 'y'
        jan = infile.readline(1-31)
        jan += counter
        print('The number of defects in January were:')

        feb = infile.readline(32-59)
        feb += counter
        print('The number of defects in February were:')

        mar = infile.readline(60-90)
        mar += counter
        print('The number of defects in March were:')

        apr = infile.readline(91-120)
        apr += counter
        print('The number of defects in April were:')

        may = infile.readline(121-151)
        may += counter
        print('The number of defects in May were:')

        jun = infile.readline(152-181)
        jun += counter
        print('The number of defects in June were:')

        jul = infile.readline(182-212)
        jul += counter
        print('The number of defects in July were:')

        aug = infile.readline(213-243)
        aug += counter
        print('The number of defects in August were:')

        sep = infile.readline(244-273)
        sep += counter
        print('The number of defects in September were:')

        oct = infile.readline(274-304)
        oct += counter
        print('The number of defects in October were:')

        nov = infile.readline(305-334)
        nov += counter
        print('The number of defects in November were:')

        dec = infile.readline(335-365)
        dec += counter
        print('The number of defects in December were:')
        print('Program ending, have a nice day.')
```

Comment: 1. *"nothing seemed to work"* is not a valid problem description. You need to debug your code first and then say what the issue specifically is (including any error messages you receive). 2. `1-31` is a mathematical expression, it does **not** signify reading "line 1 to 31" 3. `readline()` is a method that reads a single line (and does not take any parameters)

Comment: Based on the code it seems you are a beginner in Python - I recommend reading through some tutorials (including the official one on File I/O: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: When you use the readline() method it will read one line of the file and return that. The next time you use readline() it will read and return the next line. You could instead use readlines() which will return a list of all the lines in a list which you can then sort out.

Comment: Sorry, I could see as how that could be unhelpful. All I received was a TypeError: must be str, not int error code. How else would I be able to read the lines separately?

Comment: Its hard to understand what you want to achieve. Please give us an example input file and the expected output.

Comment: I'm just not understanding how to sum lines separately like 1 to 31 and 32 to 59, etc. I have made progress with a for loop but still not really getting where I want to.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop isn't really necessary.

```
infile = open('filename.txt','r')

infile_list = infile.readlines()

jan = infile_list[0:31]
feb = infile_list[31:60]
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thank you, but would I just use a for loop to sum the numbers 0-31?

Comment: The while loop is so that the user input doesn't create an infinite loop, I didn't post the rest of the code because I didn't think it was necessary and only was stuck on the first part of it

Comment: @trevor As the lines returned by readlines are strings you would have to convert each of them to an int of float, depending on what the data is. This would require a loop or list comprehension. After that is done you could use sum(jan) to get the sum.

Comment: Disregard what I said before, I got it with thanks to your help. I really appreciate it, and I'm sorry for all the dumb questions, but I gotta start somewhere.

Comment: @trevor you can't convert a list to int, you have to use a loop or list comprehension for this: jan_int = [int(x) for x in jan]